# How to always run as administrator applications on Windows

Tags: windows, uac

The problem is, when I open applications I need to always right click, select run as admin.

[image]

When I don't do it getting unexpected application errors. BTW, I turned off UAC.

It's annoying. Is there any way to change behavior of double left-click to act as "Run as administrator" action? I mean to make "Run as administrator" action by default. Thx in advance

Comment: Did you rebooted after turn off UAC?

Comment: @Ramhound Turning off UAC doesn't help in **Windows 8**, for files which are run from the `Program Files (x86)`-directory and possibly others.

Comment: @Ramhound I found this problem today with the application "Notepad++". When I open files it doesn't run the program as administrator. I had to go to the directory of Notepad++ and open it as admin, and then open the file there. This problem never occured for me before I got Windows 8. All programs were run as admin by default when UAC was off, in Windows 7, to my experience.
EDIT: and I needed the admin rights because I couldn't save the changes because it claimed the file was open in another program.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm no expert so I can't prove you wrong but I used Windows 7 for several years and never experienced problems, and I only got Windows 8 two weeks ago, so it was my first thought. Plus it keeps asking me for permission if I want to edit files in certain directories, which clued me things had changed, since I never experienced that on Windows 7, after turning UAC off, of course.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

**Method 1 (only works on shortcuts):**

1. Right-click the shortcut, click **Properties**.
2. Click Advanced. Select **Run as Administrator**.

**Method 2 (affects all shortcuts, and works on jump-lists and opening files with the application):**

1. Go to the location of the executable.
2. Right click *AppThatRequiresAdminRights.exe* and select `Troubleshoot compatibility`.
3. Select the option **Troubleshoot program** after the wizard has finished detecting issues.
4. Choose the **The program requires additional permissions** option. The wizard will apply the **Run as Administrator** setting to *AppThatRequiresAdminRights.exe* program.
5. Click <kbd>Test the program</kbd> (required) and close the wizard.

Found [here](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2012/10/16/howto-have-visual-studio-always-run-as-administrator-on-windows-8.aspx)

Comment: This is an accepted answer, howerver it shows how to always run as admin _a particular program_. When I read OP's question title, I was pretty sure, that I'll find here a solution, how to run _all programs_ in Windows 8, always as admin. Strange...

Comment: Windows tries to be retarded as Mac OS. They forgot what is their target.

Comment: +1 for the hidden feature in option 2. For a non-technical user, this might be the first he tries, but for a power-user that knows what he actually is trying to do, he will never try to "Trubleshoot program"...

Comment: I came here for this answer, even though it's not an answer to the question really :P, I launch an app via a batch file and needed it to have admin rights, this fixed it, even though the original batch file wasn't launched with admin rights. (I have UAC disabled)

Answer (score 28):

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" -Name "EnableLUA" -Value "0"
shutdown -r -t 0
```

entering on the PowerShell (started as administrator) did it for me without specifying something for every single application.

Please note that this does permanently disable UAC. Dragging the slider down in the UAC settings will not disable the UAC completely, it just won't prompt anymore but still remains active.

Comment: By definition this just removes the prompt; `EnableLUA` specifies whether Windows® User Account Controls (UAC) notifies the user when programs try to make changes to the computer. UAC was formerly known as Limited User Account (LUA).

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It completely disables UAC, you should try it at least before voting down. Btw: Prompt will be disabled when you take the slider down to the min value.

Comment: You know what, you're right my friend. I disabled UAC a much different way, through local groups, but when checked the registry key the value is in fact 0 now. Please edit your question so that I can up vote your answer. I'm sorry.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud No problem, which question do you mean? I never asked one.

Comment: I meant to say edit your answer with something more and I can change my vote.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Alright, done that

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Kill all Explorer instances and then start it again through Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) with administrative rights.

Comment: Stopped working in Windows 10

Answer (score 4):

Use the good old [Task scheduler trick which works since Vista](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=135472).

Here is a tool which help you to do the steps:

https://sites.google.com/site/freeavvarea/UACPass-en

Comment: I can get Task Scheduler to run my app but it does it in the background for non-admin users.  I need the app's UI to be visible to any account.  Is this possible?

Comment: no, the trick only works if your account is part of the admin group.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @Wolf I fixed the link

Comment: ...seems more like a complete rework ;) thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple tool to solve this problem. Read more in my CodeProject article [*Run Windows 8 Applications as Administrator by Default*](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/795876/Run-Windows-Applications-as-Administrator-by-Defau).

Comment: It is generally preferred that answers be more complete instead of relying totally on another website, which can move or go down unexpectedly.  If possible copy your answer from that site here.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

Go to the top right side of the screen in Windows 8 > click "Search" button on right panel > search for application > right click program > select "Open File Location" > click "Shortcut" tab > click "Advanced" button > check "Run As Administrator" button

Answer (score 1):

Due to AlEXIX's comment I have designed a batch store in "sendto" folder, then use right click menu "sent to" function to add "exe" in the registries run with admin right. I have tested success but each time cannot add more than fifty exe files to the registries. Also before you use the batch, cmd.exe must configured "run as admin", here is my batch code:

```
for %%i in (%*) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v %%i /d  "~ RUNASADMIN"
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for CMD in start menu and run it as administrator and enter the following command.

**net user administrator /active:yes**