# How can I run Process explorer ALWAYS as Administrator?

Tags: windows, uac

I have process explorer on my desktop, ho can I run it ALWAYS as Administrator?

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/q/505114/319765), and [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/506125/319765) in particular, but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

To run as Administrator *all* my apps as that OP was suggesting, is an overkill for me.

I have Windows 8.1 64 bits.

**EDIT:** As suggested by @Overmind I tried with a short cut, but it does not work; this is what I have in its *Properties*:

[image]

In *Avanzate* (read Advanced), I have:

[image]

Probably I should have written it before: **I have an Home Edition**, not a Pro.

Comment: Did you try making the shortcut and enable 'run as admin' ? No reason this would not work.

Comment: @Overmind It doesn't work. I edited the question with more details. Maybe I should have said berore: I have an Home Edition.

Comment: I have that option in Windows Home.

Comment: Note: the accepted answer on that other question has **2** methods. Did you try both of them? The second method works on an app by app basis and should work in Home edition as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to find the flag to set in the Compatibilità tab.

Either directly for this exe, or after you make a shortcut.