# privilege administrator for one app in windows 10

Tags: administrator, user, standards

I have a user with standard access on the domain network

This user is using software that requires admin privilege to the system

What should I do if the user only runs this program with administrator access?

I also can not change the program.

Comment: See [How to always run as administrator applications on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/505114/how-to-always-run-as-administrator-applications-on-windows)

Comment: @DocBrown OP didn't ask how to always run an application as admin, but how to run an application as admin without giving the user running it admin rights. These are not the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow this step
1.must create a user with local administrator

2.right click in shortcut program and select properties

3. in shortcut tab in front "target" Make the change as follows

open notepad and cpoy this path

C:\windows\system32\runas.exe /savecred /user:<user with acces admin loacl>

```
*In front of the user enter the computer name
*and than type username with loacl admin acces
```

Then cpoy target paht front up path As follows

C:\windows\system32\runas.exe /savecred /user:<user with acces admin loacl> “C:\Program Files (x86)\app1\app.exe”

and ok

You must enter the Local Admin user password for the first time

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to accomplish. Administrator rights are required legitimately by applications that need to make changes to all parts of the system. Only very few applications actually require this and it's very likely your application doesn't, but instead has ignorant or lazy developers who couldn't be bothered to write using standards and methods common for more than a decade now, and instead rely on being able to do any (stupid) thing they want to do in order function.

Given that requirement, in order for an application to actually run you'll have to know everything it wants to be able to do and allow that, and you'll have to figure our how the application checks for its necessary privileges and give it some way of "seeing" it is admin without it actually being run as admin.

There are tools like Process Monitor that can help inspect an applications actions to see what it needs to do.

Comment: 1. Do you know any software to monitor the program to introduce?

2. How can I allow the user to access the files and folder that the program has access to?

3.Do you think it is a good solution to join user to poweruser gruop ?

Comment: 1. My answer already suggests a software tool. 2. You didn't ask us how to do this. You're free to ask more than one question, and it's common to do this as the first problem and its answer often raises subsequent questions. 3. Phrasing a question like this WILL get it closed as opinion-based because that is what you're looking for. A note: access and permissions are very rudimentary parts of systems management and are well documented.